ASP.NET Core 8 routing with culture params and also areas
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 8 project where I have

MVC public section
Area -> MVC Admin section
Area -> Razor pages Identity area

Also I have localization to run application in English and Arabic (en, ar).
For localization, I have this code in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options =>
{
    options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
});
const string defaultCulture = "en";

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo(defaultCulture),
    new CultureInfo("ar")
};

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture);
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new UrlRequestCultureProvider()
    {
        Options = options
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRequestLocalization();
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectToDefaultCultureMiddleware>("en");

While for routing I have
app.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "areas",
   pattern: "{culture:length(2)}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Public URLs are working fine with culture based routing:
localhost:1234/en/controller/action

while when I add area in URL it do not open then page, like this:
localhost:1234/en/Identity/Account/Login

or
localhost:1234/en/Admin/Home/Index

I tried different things for routing but could not got working result to achieve culture based routing along with area

MVC Admin section:
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    pattern: "{culture=en}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Razor pages Identity area:
You can use PageRouteModelConvention to change the property routing of pages in a region
1). create a class named CustomPageRouteModelConvention :
public class CustomPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
     public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
     {
         foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
         {
             selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("Identity/", "{culture=en}/Identity/");
         }
     }
}

2).config in program.cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new CustomPageRouteModelConvention());
})
 

It runs  like this:
MVC Admin section:

Razor pages Identity area:

